# I need help with a program ia m writing in JAVA ( nullpointer exception)

Tags: java, arrays, constructor, nullpointerexception

i ma trying to write a program where about the payments of employees and other staaff, I have an abstract superclass called Employee, and then  the following FullTimeEmployee,PartTimeEmployee ,Orders and Salesman , are sub classes of Employee.
I have only one problem with null pointers in Salesman, where i try to calculate the bonus they will get for each sale.

here is my code in Salesman class

```
    public Salesman(String firstname, String lastname,int code, String address, String city,int tk,int phone,String email,int deptcode,int card,double hours,String cat,int orderno,double salary,Orders[] ord/*,double sales*/){
 super(  firstname, lastname, code,  address, city, tk, phone, email, deptcode, card, hours, cat );
 this.orderno=orderno;
 setBaseSalary( salary );

 //setGrossSales( sales );
 Orders[] order= ord.clone();//new Orders[orderno];//create the array for the orders made by this salesman
 //order=ord;
 setSallary(order );
 }



public void setSallary( Orders[] order ){
    //double sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=order.length;) {
       grossSales+=order[i++].getamount(); //get the value of the sales done
       System.out.println(grossSales);
    }
    if (grossSales<10000 ){

        baseSalary+=baseSalary*0.05;
    }
    else if((grossSales>=10000)||(grossSales<=20000)){
        baseSalary+=baseSalary*0.07;
    }
    else
        baseSalary+=baseSalary*0.1;


}
```

in main i have

```
Orders[] array=new Orders[20];
   array[0]=new Orders(1,"14/5/2010","agora aftolinitwn",2000.0);
   array[1]=new Orders(2,"14/5/2010","agora aftolinitwn",20000.0);

   Salesman sales1 =new Salesman("giannis", "antoniou",35, "vavilonos 7", "leffkosia",11475,69486931,"gäntoniou@hotmail.com",100,40,160.0,"salesman",2,1300.0,array);
   Salesman sales2 =new Salesman("andreas", "antoniou",35, "vavilonos 7", "lefkosia",11475,69486931,"äntonioua@hotmail.com",100,41,160.0,"salesman",1,1200.0,array);
```

basically what i do is creating an array with the salsmans info( amount earned from sale etc) and then sending it in to Saleman Constructor. i then copy the conents of tha array to another array an try to calulate the bonus. but i get

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
    at misthodosia.Salesman.setSallary(Salesman.java:36)
    at misthodosia.Salesman.<init>(Salesman.java:28)
    at misthodosia.Misthodosia.main(Misthodosia.java:30)
```

Java Result: 1

heres the Orders class as well

```
public class Orders {
private int orderNo;
private String orderDate;
private String description;
private double orderAmount;
private Salesman man;


public Orders(int no,String date,String descrip,double amount/*,Salesman man*/){
    orderNo=no;
    orderDate=date;
    description=descrip;
    orderAmount=amount;
    //this.man=man;

    //Orders[] orders=new Orders[orderNo];//create the array for the orders made by this salesman



}


public double getamount(){
    return orderAmount;
}
```

}

Can you help me ?? I know i am doing something wrong with the object array but i cant figure it out :S

Comment: What line of code is at `Salesman.java` line 36?

Comment: Is `order.length` correctly set to 1?

Comment: first of all thank all of you for your replies. Lets say i user array list, how do i convert this line grossSales+=order[i++].getamount(); to work with array list? i need to get that value for each element in the list ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is on this line:

grossSales+=order[i++].getamount();

The order array is allocated to a size of 20, but only the first 2 are initialized, therefore when it accesses order[2].getamount() that value is null, hence the null pointer.

I strongly recommend using an ArrayList for the list of orders, you don't have to preallocate a number of orders.

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i=0;i<=order.length;)` should be `for(int i=0;i<order.length;)`

Also, grossSales+=order[i++].getamount(); will fail for order[2] since that
element is null. You should use a collection to keep the orders (e.g. ArrayList)
or check for null before accessing members.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
Orders[] array=new Orders[20];
array[0]=new Orders(1,"14/5/2010","agora aftolinitwn",2000.0);
array[1]=new Orders(2,"14/5/2010","agora aftolinitwn",20000.0);
```

creates an array with length 20 and initialises only the first 2 entries, that means that the
other 18 enrties contain null pointers.

When you use this array, you do:

```
for(int i=0;i<=order.length;) {
   grossSales+=order[i++].getamount(); //get the value of the sales done
```

which means that at index 2 `order[i++]` will be `null` and therefore `orders[i++].getAmount()` results in a `NUllPointerException` when you dereference that `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to find null pointers like this one, what I like to do is to go to the line the Exception stack trace points out (Salesman.java:36), check what objects you are referencing on that line, and before that line add a System.out.println() for each object. One of them is bound to turn up as "null".
Then backtrack from there, and in this case you'd find (after some reasoning) Jack Cox's answer above.

Comment: first of all thank all of you for your replies. Lets say i use array list, how do i convert this line grossSales+=order[i++].getamount(); to work with array list? i need to get that value(amount) for each element(which represent a differtent order) in the list so that i can calculate the final salary of the salesman??